# Simpel Python Calculator - Syntax Error - Indentation errors

Tags: python

I recently started learning Python. I have never coded before, but it seemed like a challenge. The first thing I have made is this calculator. However, I can't seem to get it to work.

```
while True:
    print("Typ 'plus' to add two numbers")
    print("Typ 'min' to subtract two numbers")
    print("Typ 'multiplication' multiply two numbers")
    print("Typ 'division' to divide two numbers")
    print("Typ 'end' to abort the program")
    user_input = input(": ")

    if user_input == "end"
        break

    elif user_input == "plus":          
        num1 = float(input("Give a number: "))                  
        num2 = float(input("Give another number: "))
        result = str(num1 + num2)                                   
        print("The anwser is: " + str(result))

    elif user_input == "min":
        num1 = float(input("Give a number: "))                  
        num2 = float(input("Give another number: "))            
        result = str(num1 - num2)                                   
        print("The anwser is: " + str(result))

    elif user_input == "maal":
        num1 = float(input("Give a number:"))                   
        num2 = float(input("Give another number: "))            
        result = str(num1 * num2)                                   
        print("The anwser is: " + str(result))

    elif user_input == "deel":
        num1 = float(input("Give a number: "))                  
        num2 = float(input("Give another number: "))            
        result = str(num1 + num2)                                   
        print("The anwser is: " + str(result))

    else:
        print ("I don't understand!")
```

I know it will probably something stupid, I am still very much learning. Just trying to pickup a new skill instead of bothering my friends who do know how to code.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't tell us what the problem is.

Comment: It says this is invalid syntax: if user_input == "end"
    break

Comment: Also I do hope your indentation isn't like that in your source code...

Comment: Perfect, thanks! However, now it give me an error on the same line saying: 'break' outside of loop. I have tried deleting these two lines from the code. I am then promted to type which calculation I would like perform,, but then when I enter 'plus', 'min', 'division' or 'multiplication', it keeps repeating 'input'.

Comment: Indentation is an important part of the syntax and yours is way off. Please read the first parts of the tutorial again.

Comment: Great, just saw it, indeed a stupid mistake. Sorry to bother you all!

Answer (score 0):

You missed a colon after an this if statement

```
if user_input == "end"
    break
```

Should Be:

```
if user_input == "end":
    break
```